# Iterate a list of JSON objects using Django HTML tags and templates

Tags: html, json, django, django-templates, nested-loops

**Context**

I want to allow the users to aggregate a DF and create multiple tables by passing through a list of JSON objects.

**Sample Data**

```
Person_ID      hair_color      eye_color      gender
111            Brown           Brown          M
222            Blonde          Brown          M
333            Brown           Green          F
444            Brown           Blue           M
```

**Current Code**

```
 views.py
'function code to read in excel and create DF goes here'
'pull in the sample data and create a dataframe based on count of hair / eye color'
 df_list = []
 for trait in person_list:  <-- ['hair_color', 'eye_color']
     var_df = df.groupby([trait]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
     data = var_df.to_json(orient='records')
     data = json.loads(data)
     df_list.append(var_df)
 context = {'d': df_list}

 return render(request, 'URL_test', context)
 DF_LIST looks like:
[
[{'hair_color': 'Brown', 'gender': M, 'counts': 2}, {'hair_color': 'Blonde', 'gender': 'M', 'counts': 1}, {'hair_color': 'Brown', 'gender': 'F', 'counts': 1}], 
[{'eye_color': 'Brown', 'gender': 'M', 'counts': 2}, {'eye_color': 'Green', 'gender': 'F', 'counts': 1}, {'eye_color': 'Blue', 'gender': 'M', 'counts': 1}]
]

HTML Template Code:
<body>
<center>
{% if d %}
{% for i in d %}   <----- for each JSON object in DF_LIST
<div class="container">
    <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align=left>VAR NAME GOES HERE</th>    <--- dynamic based on i
            <th align=left>GENDER GOES HERE</th>
            <th align=right>COUNT</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align=left>{{i.variable}}</td>
            <td align=right>{{i.gender}}</td>
            <td align=right>{{i.counts}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

I'd like two tables to be generated in the body of the webpage that look something like this:

```
hair_color      gender     count 
brown           M          2
blonde          M          1
brown           F          1

eye_color      gender     count
brown          m          2
green          f          1
blue           m          1
```

**Problem**

Whenever I use {{ i }} as a passed through variable, it just puts the whole JSON object (which makes sense) in to the cell.  I can access index of i using {{ i.0.eye_color }} but I'm not sure how to loop through and do that for all rows in that JSON

Answer (score 0):

When looping through a dictionary you can use dictionary.items. If necessary you can loop through both keys and values as in normal python. For example `{% for i,j in d.items %}`

I also changed the location of the for loop because with the code you posted you would print out the header row every time which i don't think is the desired result.

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align=left>VAR NAME GOES HERE</th>    <--- dynamic based on i
            <th align=left>GENDER GOES HERE</th>
            <th align=right>COUNT</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for i in d.items %} 
            <tr>
                <td align=left>{{i.variable}}</td>
                <td align=right>{{i.gender}}</td>
                <td align=right>{{i.counts}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t think this would work with a list of multiple dictionary objects?  I’m aiming to print out multiple tables (which is why I had the for loop incorrectly at the beginning)

Comment: Then you need a nested loop. With the parent loop cycling through objects and the child loop cycling within the objects.